# Realm write performed on background thread still blocks Main UI

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, realm

Periodically in my app, I need to perform large writes to Realm, anywhere between 100 to 10,000 objects. Obviously this is a large write, so I'm attempting to perform this write in the background so that the user can perform other operations and not even notice the write. Unfortunately, even though I thought my write was being performed on a background thread, the main UI still gets blocked. Here is the jist of the method that I call to perform the writes to realm. This method is called repeatedly on single objects from an array I'm looping through. Does it look like I'm doing anything blatantly wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
func writeCustomerToRealm(inputCustomer:Customer) {
  let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
  let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
  dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.beginWrite()
    realm.add(self.swapCustomerForRealmCustomer(inputCustomer))
    try! realm.commitWrite()
 })
}
```

Comment: Can you share what the main thread is doing when it is blocking? A stack trace while it is blocked would be particularly interesting.

Comment: As in stack trace from System Trace or Time Profiler in Instruments @bdash ?

Comment: Yes, Time Profiler should show what the main thread is doing. Even breaking in the debugger when the main thread is blocked and looking at the stack trace of the main thread may be sufficient to see what the main thread is blocked on.

Comment: @Amloelxer, could you use a site like imgur so we don't have to download content from a site to view your image?

Comment: @ZGSki I uploaded it like that because it's not an image, but the full XCode instrument trace. If you would like to download it, all you have to do is click the "Time Profiler Stack Trace Record.trace.zip" in green

Comment: The sample shows a lot of time being spent on the main thread processing web socket messages (~45% of the time captured by the Instruments trace). A lot of that time appears to be due to inefficient use of `NSDateFormatter`. From what I can see there's effectively zero time spent in Realm on the main thread. What lead you to think Realm is a factor in your main thread blocking?

Comment: @bdash is right, this seems less and less like an issue with Realm saving asynchronously, and more of something related to the `DateFormatter`. How exactly are you utilizing and when are you calling the `NSDateFormatter`?

Comment: @bdash I assumed it had to be Realm because I didn't think anything as seemingly trivial as NSDateFormatter could cause the blockage. It seems though that you are completely right, and I need to look more into my inefficient use of NSDateFormatter. Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I posted an answer with the same information for sake of completeness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your provided code is the correct way to perform an asynchronous, background write using Realm. It should not block the main thread unless the main thread itself attempts to perform a write transaction while the background write is in progress.

The instruments trace you shared indicates that the majority of the non-idle time spent on the main thread is spent processing web socket messages. There's no indication of any work related to Realm occurring on the main thread. The web socket message processing on the main thread accounts for 45% of the total time period of the trace, and is likely the cause of the blocked UI you're experiencing. The majority of the web socket processing time is spent performing work related to `NSDateFormatter`. In particular, the `NSDateFormatter` appears to be frequently regenerating its underlying `CFDateFormatter`. This suggests that properties of the `NSDateFormatter` are being frequently updated, or that new `NSDateFormatter` instances are being used for each call. Both of those practices should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks so much bdash! This was the fix. Appreciate the help