# Periodically save an object in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, realm

I have a Realm object called `Trip`. It stores data of a user's movement.

```
class Trip: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var startTimestamp: Int64 = 0
    dynamic var endTimestamp: Int64 = 0
    dynamic var distance: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var calories: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var averageSpeed: Double = 0.0
}
```

In the view controller, I keep a class-level variable called `trip`.

```
fileprivate var trip: Trip?
```

Whenever a user starts a trip, I initialize a `Trip` object and assigns it to this variable.

```
trip = Trip()
```

And throughout the user's movements, I keep updating this `trip` object with the data.

I need to save this data to the Realm database every 1 minute. So I run a timer.

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(save()), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Which executes a function to save this object in a background thread.

```
fileprivate func save() {
    do {
        DispatchQueue(label: "RealmBackgroundThread").async {
            autoreleasepool {
                let realm = try! Realm()
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(self.trip!, update: true)
                }
            }
        }

    } catch {

    }
}
```

Up to here, it works fine. The problem is after the first save, when I try to access that `trip` object again, it crashes with the following error.

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type realm::IncorrectThreadException: Realm accessed from incorrect thread.

I think this happens because I open a new `Realm` to save this object in a background thread. I know that Realm isn't thread-safe.

But I'm not sure how to resolve this. How do I keep using the same `trip` object after saving it?

Comment: Have you read this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123936/realm-write-performed-on-background-thread-still-blocks-main-ui ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from Realm's documentation about [Passing Instances Across Threads](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#passing-instances-across-threads):

> Instances of `Realm`, `Results`, or `List`, or managed instances of `Object` are thread-confined, meaning that they can only be used on the thread on which they were created, otherwise an exception is thrown.

In your case, `self.trip` is a managed instance of an `Object` subclass, and you appear to be accessing it from both the main thread, and repeatedly from the serial dispatch queue you create within your `save()` method. It's important to keep in mind that the call to `DispatchQueue.async` will result in your code being executed on *different threads* depending on the whims of Grand Central Dispatch. That is to say that two consecutive calls like …

```
DispatchQueue(label: "RealmBackgroundThread").async {
    // work
}
```

… will often result in the work being performed on two different threads.

Realm's documentation on [Passing Instances Across Threads](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#passing-instances-across-threads) contains an example of how to pass a thread-safe reference to an object across threads and resolve it in the `Realm` instance on the target thread.

It's hard to provide a more specific suggestion in your case as I'm not clear what you're trying to do with your `save()` method and why you're calling it on a timer. Managed `Object` instances (instances retrieved from a Realm, or that have already been added to a Realm) can only be modified within a write transaction, so any modifications to `self.trip` would need to be performed within the write transaction opened by your `save()` method for it to serve any purpose. For the pattern of using a timer to make sense you'd need to leave `self.trip` as an *unmanaged* object, at which point `save()` would update the `Trip` instance with the same ID in the Realm file. To do this you'd want to use `Realm.create(_:value:update:)` instead of `Realm.add(_:update:)`, as `create` does not convert unmanaged instances to managed instances like `add` does.

Comment: Thank you. Using `Realm.create(_:value:update:)` worked.